# How to alter a form depending how it was accessed

Tags: users, 6

I would like to alter the login form depending how it was accessed. As an example, if the form was access from a particular link, it would display the standard login form. If it was accessed from a different link, then the login form would be modified (ie maybe display a different title and exhibit different behaviour (redirects based on role)).

I figure I need to use hook_form_alter() but I am not sure how to tell which link was clicked. Any ideas how one would go about accomplishing this? I am working with Drupal 6 by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `form_alter()` hook, you can always check what page a form is on by looking at `$_GET['q']`, eg:

```
if ($form_id=='user_login' && $_GET['q']=='different/link') {
  // do form alters here
}
```

so if you are at `www.yourhost.com/different/link`, it will do whatever you tell it to do.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried this and it didn't work. I will look at my implementation again and see if I did something wrong.

Comment: let me know, the approach above does work, but the login form is also pretty unique in a lot of ways, especially with redirection, so, it could be something else that is masking the behavior.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to this sooner but I had a bunch of other stuff on my plate to deal with. I looked at my code more closely and saw that I didn't have it quite set up like you suggested. I changed it to match and it worked. The only thing I had to change was to get the clean url instead the internal url. Otherwise worked great!